# WildFly has permissions errors with temporary files, on every other start up

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-9

I work on a Java EE application at work that deploys to Wildfly 9 final, and every other startup it throws a permissions error related to temporary files. This is very consistent, and is fixed by restarting Wildfly. To give a sample of the output:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\Application Servers\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\standalone\\tmp\\vfs\\temp\\tempae5804842caf81bd\\content-8ea30ac4d95617b7\\content-1681167519349174010.tmp (Access is denied)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\Application Servers\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\standalone\\tmp\\vfs\\temp\\tempae5804842caf81bd\\content-8ea30ac4d95617b7\\content-1681167519349174010.tmp (Access is denied)"}}
```

Does anyone know the utility of these, and a way to stop this from happening? It's a recurring mild annoyance.

Comment: are you always starting Wildfly using the same user?

Comment: I am, same user same system. Also happens if I force redeploy the war instead of restarting Wildfly.

Comment: and if you just delete the tmp folder (I think this should be possible at least a development stages without problems), does it re-occur?

Comment: I'll have a look, it's on my office system which I don't have access to. If that does work might be worth automating it in my bat scripts

Comment: What happens if you don't use a space in the path?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the lines below from your standalone.xml.

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
```

It worked for me.